# Generic interface constraint

Tags: c#, generics, interface, casting

I have a question about generics and the use of interfaces cast when creating concret classes:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    interface ITest
    {

    }

    class Timpl : ITest
    {

    }

    class Test<T> where T : ITest
    {
        public T get()
        {
            return default(T);
        }
    }

    class MyClass
    {
        public MyClass()
        {
            Test<ITest> s = new Test<Timpl>(); //Does not compile
        }
    }
}
```

I read up on co- and contravariant, but I must be missing something, or it has nothing to do what I'm trying, or it just doesnt work what I'm trying to do.

I though I could make the cast from Test to Test because TImple inherits from ITest.

Comment: Have you not found any of the provided answers useful? Don't forget to mark it as accepted by checking a green mark below the answer score.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think  I understand your problem.  You can read about covariance and contravariance  at the following  MSDN link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee207183.aspx

My Solution to your problem looks like this

interface ITest
    {
    }

```
class TImpl:ITest
{

}

interface ITest<out T>
{
    T get();
}

class Test<T>:ITest<T> 
          where T:ITest
{
    public T get()
    {
        return default(T);
    }
}
```

As you can see ,  I've added  and interface over  your  Test class and I've marked the Type argument, T, as out.   Now you can do  the following:

```
 ITest<ITest> t = new Test<TImpl>();
```

I hope  this helps

Answer (score 3):

It should be

```
class Test<T> where T : ITest
{
    public T get()
    {
        return default(T);
    }
}
```

Then create an instance of `Test` like

```
var s = new Test<Timpl>();
```

**EDIT:**

Based on the comment below. Ok, now you are dealing with covariance and contravariance. If you need to specify

```
Test<ITest> s = new Test<Timpl>();
```

then it can't work because only generic type parameters of interfaces and delegates can be marked as covariant or contravariant.

However, you could solve it by making `Test` implement an interface.

```
interface ITestClass<out T>
{
    T get();
}

class Test<T> : ITestClass<T> where T : ITest
{
    public T get()
    {
        return default(T);
    }
}

ITestClass<ITest> s = new Test<Timpl>(); // Does compile
```

Comment: Sorry, but didn't notice that it didnt write the greaterthen and lessthen tags. So the example is alittle differnt now.

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    interface ITest
    {
    }

    class Timpl : ITest
    {
    }

    class Test<T> where T : ITest
    {
        public T get()
        {
            return default(T);
        }
    }

    public class mycls : ITest
    {
    }

    class MyClass
    {
        public MyClass()
        {
            Test<mycls> s = new Test<mycls>(); //will compile
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why create `mycls` when OP already has an implementantion of `ITest`? It seems that he just doesn't know how to use it.

Comment: Sorry, but didn't notice that it didnt write the greaterthen and lessthen tags. So the example is alittle differnt now.